# iOS VoiceOver not reading out nested <ul> element

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover

Reading this with VoiceOver enabled only reads the initial list elements, and does not navigate to the the nested list elements (underneath the second nested `ul` elements) when using the swipe left-to-right gesture.

ANy ideas as to why this happens?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head
  </head>
  <div>
    <ul role="menu">
      <li role="menuitem">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="true">Expand</a>
        <ul role="menu">
          <li role="menuitem">
            <a href="#"  role="button">
              Link One
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="menuitem">
            <a href="#" role="button">
              Link Two
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li role="menuitem">
        <a href="#"aria-expanded="true">Expand 2</a>
        <ul role="menu">
          <li role="menuitem">
            <a href="#" role="button">
              Link Three
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="menuitem">
            <a href="#" role="button">
              Link Four
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your links the `menuitem` instead of the `<li>`.
On the `<li>`'s, add `role=presentation`.

```
<div>
  <ul role="menu">
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="#" aria-expanded="true" role="menuitem">Expand</a>
      <ul role="menu">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">
            Link One
          </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">
            Link Two
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="#" aria-expanded="true" role="menuitem">Expand 2</a>
      <ul role="menu">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">
            Link Three
          </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">
            Link Four
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Note:** You should only be using `menu`/`menuitem` if you are going to allow the user to navigate through your menu using the arrow keys (on a desktop, obviously, not mobile).  If the user has to use the Tab key to navigate, then `menu`/`menuitem` should **not** be used.  You would just have `aria-expanded` on your submenus to indicate whether the submenu was open or not.

If `menu`/`menuitem` are being used appropriatly (arrow key navigation), then your submenus should also have `aria-haspopup="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use those `a` tags before the submenus (which are not real links, they actually lead to the top of the page, which isn't really correct), but integrate the `aria-expanded="true"` attribute in the `li` tags,

To get a "link-like" appearance, you could still apply anotherr color, text-decoration and cursor to those `li` elements, but there's no reason to use an `a` tag there (at least not judging from the code you posted)

```html
<div>
  <ul role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem" aria-expanded="true">Expand
      <ul role="menu">
        <li role="menuitem">
          <a href="#" role="button">Link One</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem">
          <a href="#" role="button">Link Two</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem" aria-expanded="true">Expand 2
      <ul role="menu">
        <li role="menuitem">
          <a href="#" role="button">Link Three</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem">
          <a href="#" role="button">Link Four</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```